# How know who linked turtle?

Tags: netlogo

I have two linked turtles randomly assigned by distance in the neighborhood. However, I can't find out what the number of the who turtles is linked.

I try. let x [who] of link-with turtle 0. but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If I am not interpreting wrong what you ask, you could do that with:

```
ask turtle 0 [let x [who] of link-neighbors]
```

As turtles are linked by pairs, using link-neighbors will only make reference to the other turtle in the link.